# How can I change my applicatoin resource without source rebuilding?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, embedded-resource, il, reflector

I develop a .net application many years ago.
My customer wants to making some simple changes on application.
But I **lost** my codes?

Is there any solution to modifying some resources in my application?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you can reverse engineer an application (perhaps by using a tool like Red Gates's Reflector), to get the source code back (although it won't be the same as the original, as reverse engineering makes a number of 'best guesses')

If you're referring to resources in .resx files, these aren't compiled so should be editable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I prepared Reflector and Reflexil, but I don't know how can I inject change a background picture in resources